# Add custom attribute file in Windows 7 via CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a problem with the command `attrib`.
The problem is that I can't add my own attribute eg. "toRemove".
In the documentation, there is nothing about adding custom attributes.
I tried to change the command `attrib +h file.txt` to `attrib +toRemove file.txt` or `attrib file.txt [+toRemove]`, but it does not work.

Comment: There's a reason there's nothing in the documentation about adding attributes. The reason is that you cannot do so. [Wishful thinking does not cause features to spring into existence](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/27/10353605.aspx).

Comment: For NTFS you could add this attribute to an alternate data stream. Here's a crude command prompt example. Define attributes as a bit mapping: `set /a "attrs = %TO_REMOVE% | %TO_WIPE%"`. Store it to an "attributes" stream: `echo %attrs% >file.txt:attributes`. Display it via `more <file.txt:attributes` or in a loop with `for /f %i in (file.txt:attributes) do @(echo %i)`. Show it in a directory listing using `dir /r file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The default attributes of `R`, `A`, `S`, and `H` (and `I`) are the only ones that `attrib` can use natively. You could write a shell extension to support your custom attributes.